# setTimeout callback argument

Tags: javascript

Let's consider this piece of JavaScript:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.showName = function() {
    alert(this.name);
}


var mike = new Person("mike");
//mike.showName();  

window.name = "window";
```

I don't understand the difference between the behavior of

```
setTimeout(mike.showName(), 5000);
```

and

```
setTimeout(function(){
    mike.showName();
}, 5000);
```

Why is the behavior different? It really confuses me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the OP means "behavior" when he says "performance".

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Your question really has *nothing at all* to do with `setTimeout`. You simply need to understand the difference between a function call and a reference to a function.

Consider these four assignments:

```
var one = function() { mike.showName(); };
var two = mike.showName;
var three = mike.showName();
var four = (function() { mike.showName(); })();
```

The first two assign a reference to a function to their respective variables. The last two, however, *call* functions (that's what the parens are for) and assign their return values to the vars on the left-hand side.

**How this relates to setTimeout:**

The `setTimeout` function expects as its first argument a *reference* to a function, so either `one` or `two` above would be correct, but `three` and `four` would not. However, it is important to note that it is not, strictly speaking, a *mistake* to pass the return value of a function to `setTimeout`, although you'll frequently see that said.

This is perfectly fine, for example:

```
function makeTimeoutFunc(param) {
    return function() {
        // does something with param
    }
}

setTimeout(makeTimeoutFunc(), 5000);
```

It has nothing to do with *how* `setTimeout` receives a function as its argument, but *that it does*.

Comment: Thanks a  lot man. Your answer is great. However I still have one confusion. Could you tell me why 'mike.showName()' would be executed first while 'function(){ mike.showName()' waits its 5 seconds? Thanks again.

Comment: @jsnewman - Passing `mike.showName()` says to run the function `showName` right now and pass whatever it returns as the callback to be executed in 5 seconds (which is nothing). However, passing `function(){ mike.showName() }` provides `setTimeout` with an anonymous function to run five seconds from now. Five seconds go by and the outer wrapper function is executed. It contains one line, which is the call to `showName`, which is executed at that time.

Answer (score 27):

If the accepted answer is just too long to read:

```
setTimeout(mike.showName(), 5000);
```

This will execute whatever `mike.showName()` **returns** after 5,000 milliseconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){ mike.showName(); }, 5000);
```

This will execute anonymous function after 5000 milliseconds that calls `mike.showName()`  , **the actual function**.

Another way to achieve same effect:

```
setTimeout(mike.showName.bind(mike), 5000);
```

Answer (score 10):

It's not a performance issue. One of the ways you showed simply doesn't work (it calls the function immediately instead of when the timeout fires).

`setTimeout(mike.showName(), 5000);` will execute the `showName` function and sets its return value as the timeout callback which won't work.

`setTimeout(function(){ mike.showName(); }, 5000);` creates an anonymous function and sets this as the timeout callback. When the timeout fires, the function is called and calls your `showName()` function.

Fyi, `setTimeout('mike.showName();', 5000);` would also work. But **don't do that** - it's just as bad as using `eval()`. Besides that it makes your code less readable since the code in the string cannot be syntax-highlighted.

Comment: Could you tell me why 'mike.showName()' would be executed first while 'function(){ mike.showName()' waits its time? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Because you actually call the function in that line. If you wrap it in an anonymous function or just pass the function without `()` it's not called - the function itself is passed.

Answer (score 6):

`setTimeout(mike.showName(), 5000);` executes `mike.showName()` immediately and passes the return value to `setTimeout()`

`setTimeout(function(){ mike.showName(); }, 5000);` passes a pointer to the function instead.  That way `setTimeout` can execute the function, rather than it's return value.