# Confused about first argument in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm having great trouble understanding the first argument for `setTimeout` and how the delay argument effects it.

The way I understand `setTimeout` is:

```
setTimeout(foo, don't even think about foo until x miliseconds has passed)
```

But if we consider this code:

```
<div id="mine"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function go(){
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("mine");
        myDiv.innerHTML = "Hello World";    
}

setTimeout(go(), 2000)
</script>
```

`go` is run right away without waiting 2 seconds.

As many before me have pointed out, `setTimeout(go(), 2000)` is asking for the return value when I actually want `setTimeout(go, 2000)`.

Frankly, I don't understand the difference other than "one works, and one doesn't." Why doesn't the former also respect the delay argument?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520155/settimeout-callback-argument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function in JavaScript is an object. `go` is the function object, `go()` executes the `go` function and returns its value. `setTimeout` expects a function, thus `go`, not `go()`.

```
function go(){
  return 'hello';
}

console.log(go); //=> function go(){}, a function object
console.log(go()); //=> 'hello', a string returned by the function `go`
```

Comment: So if we consider an anonymous function like `setTimeout(function(){console.log("go"), 2000}` the anon function is loaded into memory immediately, and then fired after two seconds? I'm trying to understand the order in which setTimeout is processed.

Comment: @nipponese: Yes. You define the function in that position, and it will return the variable pointing toward the anonymous function, so it can be called in the same way as described above.

Comment: So basically, `setTimeout` always checks to see that the first argument is a function object, and if it's not an object, it just runs the function immediately as a de facto error state?

Comment: If you execute the function instead of passing a reference then it will run once and `setTimout` will do nothing.

Answer (score -3):

```
var go = function () {
  console.log('GO GO GO!');
};

setTimeout(go, 2000);
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to explain the question asked. Did you even read it?

Comment: Not asking "how," but "why."