# dblClick and click event in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can i make dblClick and click  events on the selection?

```
  serverIcons.filter(function(d) {
            return d.linktoLayermodel
        }).on('click', function(d) {
            if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
            alert('click');

        }).on('dblclick', function(){alert('dblclick');});
```

But when do dblclick it alerts me 'click'

Comment: Did you research this ? Took me 2 seconds to find an answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307185/d3-how-do-i-set-click-event-and-dbclick-event-at-the-same-time

Comment: Ya i got the solution from above link :)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546040/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-ondblclick-on-an-element