# Both single and double click on a node in d3 force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, d3-force-directed

I'm creating a d3 force directed graph. My requirement is to have both single click and double click on a node.
On single click , i need to perform different tasks and on double click , some other task.

This is what my code looks like:

```
var node = svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "nodes")
          .selectAll("circle")
          .data(graph.nodes)
          .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
          .attr("r", 5)
          .on("click",function(d){ alert("node was single clicked"); })
          .on("dblclick",function(d){ alert("node was double clicked"); })
```

The problem here is , even though I double click on the node, single click function is called.

How do i prevent `click` function to be called when I double click on the node.
In other words, when node is single clicked, then `click` function has to be called, when double clicked, then `dblclick` function has to be called.

Many thanks to anyone who can help me solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3: How do I set "click" event and "dbclick" event at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307185/d3-how-do-i-set-click-event-and-dbclick-event-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can distinguish between single click and double click using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), check the demo:

```js
var timeout = null;

d3.select('rect').on("click", function(d) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      console.clear();
      console.log("node was single clicked", new Date());
    }, 300)
  })
  .on("dblclick", function(d) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    
    console.clear();
    console.log("node was double clicked", new Date());
  });
```

```css
rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
Open the console and click / double click on the rect:
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This saved so much effort