# How to execute callback after function has returned

Tags: javascript

I can't get my head around callbacks. Here is a simple example to show what I'm confused about. The callback printData needs to be called after getData has returned.

```
function data(cb) {

   var myData = getData();  
    cb(myData);
}

function printData(data) {

    console.log("printing " + data)   
}

function getData () {

    console.log("getting data");

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("finishing data");
        return "this is the data"
    }), 3000;
}

data(printData);

//OUTPUT

//getting data
//printing undefined
//finishing data
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xsrLeo9u/1/)

Comment: `getData` does return immediately. The `return` in the `setTimeout` callback is useless. `getData` needs to take a callback as well.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5520190/185672

Comment: Why do you need a callback there? It doesn't seem to be useful at all in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update your function to following

```
function data(cb) {

   getData(cb);  // pass the callback function

}

function printData(data) {

    console.log("printing " + data)   
}

function getData (cb) {

    console.log("getting data");

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("finishing data");
        cb("this is the data"); // call the callback function
        //return "this is the data" // this return is useless, remove it
    }), 3000;
}

data(printData);
```

For reference - https://jsfiddle.net/xsrLeo9u/2/